How to get the auth token in an SPI?
I'm currently working on a Service Provider Interface (SPI) for Keycloak, and I'm facing a challenge that I hope someone can help me with.
I need to send the Keycloak authorization token to an external service, exchange it for another token, and then either attach this new token to a cookie or include it as a custom claim.
Where and how can I access the token within the Keycloak SPI to send it to the external service? At which stage or method can I perform this operation to ensure the token is available?
What I've tried:
Custom Claim:
I attempted to use a custom claim to retrieve the token, but I couldn't get the token as a JWT.
Authentication Flow:
I also tried to perform this operation as part of the authentication flow, but it failed. I suspect this is because the token isn't generated yet at that point.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
